# Avoid landing page redirects in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am working on a Wordpress website, and I ran gtmetrix to see its performance. I keep getting:

Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs.

[http://inspiringworm.com/](https://inspiringworm.com/)

https://inspiringworm.com/

https://www.inspiringworm.com/

Does anyone know how to get rid of these redirects? Is it coming from a certain module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the link and make sure you have the full address: `https://www.inspiringworm.com/`. The other two just redirect, as gtmetrix explains.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a website is working based on protocols and URL.
There are 4 kind of possible URL combinations: 
1) HTTP + WWW 
2) HTTP + NON_WWW 
3) HTTPS + WWW 
4) HTTPS + NON_WWW.

Your website is forcefully running with HTTPS protocol and with WWW. If you will check in GTMATRIX/any other tool/browser, it will load the content from HTTPS and WWW, better to check it with [inspiringworm website](https://www.inspiringworm.com/) like https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.inspiringworm.com/MIPLD7Co